# How to change separator color in my IDesigner?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, designer

I just created my own library with designer control,that used from System.ComponentModel.Design reference.So i got a winform designer in my application,like in vs.But i dont like that separator white color,how i can change it,because i dont found the property of separator color.I know that is possible to change the separator color like to grey color,because visual studio separator is grey...
Image: First image is visual studio separator in designer,
Second image is ugly white separator in my IDesignerHost designer..
[image: how designer in vs is looks like]
[image: how my designer looks like(used from System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesigner]
i we tried to find some property of separator color in IDesigner and IDesignerHost,but i dont found..please help me..

How my library with `IDesignerHost` is works:

```cs
//surface is interface of my implemented designer,so i can get it as control
//to change basic properties,like backcolor,font,etc...
//but also i can get it as IDesigner and IDesignerHost
//but how to change a separator color?
DesignSurface surface = new DesignSurface();
Control view = surface.GetView(); //returns control or IDesigner/IDesignerHost
view.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the splitter from `Controls` collection of the view of the [`DesignSurface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designsurface?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). The splitter will be added as soon as you have a component in the component tray. So you can use this code to change color of the splitter.

**Example**

You can try it using the following code. Just make sure you have added a reference to `System.Design` assembly and using `System.Linq` and `System.ComponentModel.Design` namespaces:

```
var surface = new DesignSurface();
var host = (IDesignerHost)surface.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
surface.BeginLoad(typeof(Form));
var root = (Form)host.RootComponent;
host.CreateComponent(typeof(BindingSource), "bindingSource1");
var view = (Control)surface.View;
view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
view.BackColor = Color.White;
var splitter = view.Controls.OfType<Splitter>().FirstOrDefault();
if (splitter != null)
    splitter.BackColor = Color.Red;
else
{
    view.ControlAdded += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Control is Splitter)
            args.Control.BackColor = Color.Red;
    };
}
this.Controls.Add(view);
```

And you will get a result like:

[image]